# Parsing / Scraping information from an image

Tags: image-processing, ocr

I am looking for a library that would help scrape the information from the image below.
I need the current value so it would have to recognise the values on the left and then estimate the value of the bottom line.

Any ideas if there is a library out there that could do something like this? Language isn't really important but I guess Python would be preferable.

Thanks

[image: Image to Scrape]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any "out of the box" solution for this and I doubt one exists. If all you have is the image, then you'll need to do some image processing. A simple binarization method (like Otsu binarization) would make it easier to process:

[image: Binarized image]

The binarization makes it easier because now the pixels are either "on" or "off."

The locations for the lines can be found by searching for some number of pixels that are all on horizontally (5 on in a row while iterating on the x axis?).

Then a possible solution would be to pass the image to an OCR engine to get the numbers (tesseractOCR is an open source OCR engine hosted at Google (C++): [tesseractOCR](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/)). You'd still have to find out where the numbers are in the image by iterating through it.

Then, you'd have to find where the lines are relative to the keys on the left and do a little math and you can get your answer.

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a beefy computer vision library that has things like the binarization. It is also a C++ library.

Hope that helps.